# Angular 7 Dynamically generating radio buttons from server side json

Tags: angular

I am trying to Dynamically generate radio buttons based on the results of a server side call.

My Service looks like this:

```
 getCancelReasons():  Observable<CancelReason> {
    const href =  environment.apiUrl + 'api/v1/CancelReason/ListActive';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}`;
             return this.http.get<CancelReason>(requestUrl, {
              headers: {'Token': 'token'}
            });
  }
```

My Cancel Reason Model looks like this

```
    export class CancelReason {
        cancelReasonId: number;
        description: string;
        active: boolean;
        deleted: boolean;
    }
```

My Component.ts looks like this

```
export class CancelContractComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoadingCancelReasons: boolean;
    cancelReasonList: CancelReason[];


    constructor(private data: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadCancelReasons();
    }


    loadCancelReasons() {
        this.isLoadingCancelReasons = true;
        this.data.getCancelReasons().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.cancelReasonList = data;
            this.isLoadingCancelReasons = false;
        },
        (error) => {
            this.isLoadingCancelReasons = false;
        }
        );
    }
}
```

My component.html looks like this

```
<div *ngFor="let cancelReason of cancelReasonList; let i = index">
        <input type="radio">
    <label>{{ cancelReason[i].name }}</label>
    </div>
```

The data from the server looks like this

```
[
  {
    "cancelReasonId": 1,
    "description": "A.10 Bill Date",
    "active": true,
    "deleted": false
  },
  {
    "cancelReasonId": 2,
    "description": "A.11 Bill Frequency",
    "active": true,
    "deleted": false
  },
 ...
]
```

I see a list of radio buttons but no text and value
[image]

Comment: `cancelReason[i].name` I dont see a property called `name`. Did you mean `description`? Also you dont see a value cause you didn't bind a value.

Comment: @ug I do mean description. How can I bind the value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to display `description` rather than `name` since its not existing on your variable

```
<div *ngFor="let cancelReason of cancelReasonList; let i = index">
  <input type="radio">
  <label>{{ cancelReason.description }}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate dynamic forms coming from the server, use [NG Dynamic Forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) library, it is pretty simple and does the job pretty well, here is a [demo](http://ng2-dynamic-forms.udos86.de/sample/index.aot.html#/material-sample-form)

You can also read the [Angular Dynamic Form Guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) to implement your own dynamic forms logic.